# Save a string value in resources [C#] EDIT: not resources but Properties.Settings

Tags: c#, winforms, save

I am making a `Windows Forms Application` where you can save your logins such as username or password. My goal is to find a way to save them somewhere so if I close the program and open it again all my saved logins (username, password...) 
are shown to the user as they were before exiting. I am searching a way to create new string values in a resource folder.

So I was wondering if there is a way to save them into the `Properties.Resources`.

Thanks!

Comment: You can create a text file and store all information that you want. And you can save the text file to everywhere. even resources..

Comment: Thanks! The problem with that is if I am going to put the path of the .txt file into the code: StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\'Username'\Documents\Visual Studio\Projects\'SolutionName'\Resources");
it's only going to work for me because if I am going to give the program to someone else it won't work because he will have a different path and if I will use Properties.Resources it will always be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably aren't looking for `Properties.Resources`, but for Application Settings. These can be created in the designer and accessed and saved during runtime.

Access with: `Properties.Settings.Default.MyProperty`

Save with: `Properties.Settings.Default.Save()`

Here is an [MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh.aspx) on the subject.

Comment: I looked it up on youtube too, and find out how I could use it.
Thank you very much!